# Does computing screen space for reflections/refractions require second partial derivatives?

Tags: trigonometry, raytracing, antialiasing

I have written a basic raytracer which keeps track of screen space. Each fragment has an associated pixel radius. When a ray `dir` hits the geometry when extruded by some `distance` from an `eye`, I compute the normal vector `N` for the hit, and combine it with four more rays. In pseudocode:

```
def distance := shortestDistanceToSurface(sdf, eye, dir, pixelRadius)
def p := eye + dir * distance
def N := estimateNormal(sdf, p)
def glance := distance * glsl.dot(dir, N)
def dx := (dirPX / glsl.dot(dirPX, N) - dirNX / glsl.dot(dirNX, N)) * glance
def dy := (dirPY / glsl.dot(dirPY, N) - dirNY / glsl.dot(dirNY, N)) * glance
```

Here, `dirPX`, `dirNX`, `dirPY`, and `dirNY` are rays which are offset by `dir` by the pixel radius in screen space in each of the four directions, but still aiming at the same reference point. This gives `dx` and `dy`, which are partial derivatives across the pixel indicating the rate at which the hit moves along the surface of the geometry as the rays move through screen space.

Because I track screen space, I can use [pre-filtered samplers, as discussed by Inigo Quilez](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/checkerfiltering/checkerfiltering.htm). They look great. However, now I want to add reflection (and refraction), which means that I need to recurse, and I'm not sure how to compute these rays and track screen space.

The essential problem is that, in order to figure out what color of light is being reflected at a certain place on the geometry, I need to not just take a point sample, but examine the whole screen space which is reflected. I can use the partial derivatives to give me four new points on the geometry which approximate an ellipse which is the projection of the original pixel from the screen:

```
def px := dx * pixelRadius
def py := dy * pixelRadius
def pPX := p + px
def pNX := p - px
def pPY := p + py
def pNY := p - py
```

And I can compute an approximate pixel radius by smushing the ellipse into a circle. I know that this ruins certain kinds of desirable anisotropic blur, but what's a raytracer without cheating?

```
def nextRadius := (glsl.length(dx) * glsl.length(dy)).squareRoot() * pixelRadius
```

However, I don't know where to reflect those points into the geometry; I don't know where to focus their rays. If I have to make a choice of focus, then it will be arbitrary, and depending on where the geometry reflects its own image, then this could arbitrarily blur or moiré the reflected images.

**Do I need to take the second partial derivatives?** I can approximate them just like the first derivatives, and then I can use them to adjust the normal `N` with slight changes, just like with the hit `p`. The normals then guide the focus of the ellipse, and map it to an approximate conic section. I'm worried about three things:

1. I worry about the cost of doing a couple extra vector additions and multiplications, which is probably negligible;
2. And also about whether the loss in precision, which is already really bad when doing these cheap derivatives, is going to be too lossy over multiple reflections;
3. And finally, how I'm supposed to handle situations where screen space explodes; when I have a mirrored sphere, how am I supposed to sample over big wedges of reflected space and e.g. average a checkerboard pattern into a grey?

And while it's not a worry, I simply don't know how to take four vectors and quickly fit a convincing cone to them, but this might be a mere problem of spending some time doing algebra on a whiteboard.

Edit: In John Amanatides' 1984 paper [Ray Tracing with Cones](https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/%7Eamana/research/cones.pdf), the curvature information is indeed computed, and used to fit an estimated cone onto the reflected ray. In Homan Igehy's 1999 paper [Tracing Ray Differentials](https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/trd/trd_jpg.pdf), only the first-order derivatives are used, and second derivatives are explicitly ignored.

Are there other alternatives, maybe? I've experimented with discarding the pixel radius after one reflection and just taking point samples, and they look horrible, with lots of aliasing and noise. Perhaps there is a field-of-view or depth-of-field approximation which can be computed on a per-material basis. As usual, multisampling can help, but I want an analytic solution so I don't waste so much CPU needlessly.

(`sdf` is a [signed distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) and I am doing sphere tracing; the same routine both computes distance and also normals. `glsl` is the GLSL standard library.)

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept my own answer, but I'll explain what I've done so that I can put this question down for now. I ended up going with an approach similar to Amanatides, computing a cone around each ray.

Each time I compute a normal vector, I also compute the mean curvature. Normal vectors are computed using a well-known trick. Let `p` be a zero of the SDF as in my question, let `epsilon` be a reasonable offset to use for [numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation), and then let `vp` and `vn` be vectors whose components are evaluations of the SDF near `p` but perturbed at each component by `epsilon`. In pseudocode:

```
def justX := V(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
def justY := V(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
def justZ := V(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
def vp := V(sdf(p + justX * epsilon), sdf(p + justY * epsilon), sdf(p + justZ * epsilon))
def vn := V(sdf(p - justX * epsilon), sdf(p - justY * epsilon), sdf(p - justZ * epsilon))
```

Now, by clever abuse of [finite difference coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient), we can compute both first and second derivatives at the same time. The third coefficient, `sdf(p)`, is already zero by assumption. This gives our normal vector `N`, which is the gradient, and our mean curvature `H`, which is the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

```
def N := glsl.normalize(vp - vn)
def H := sum(vp + vn) / (epsilon * epsilon)
```

We can estimate Gaussian curvature from mean curvature. While mean curvature tells our cone how much to expand or contract, Gaussian curvature is always non-negative and measures how much extra area ([spherical excess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Excess)) is added to the cone's area of intersection. Gaussian curvature is given with `K` instead of `H`, and after substituting:

```
def K := H * H
```

Now we're ready to adjust the computation of fragment width. Let's assume that, in addition to the `pixelRadius` in screen space and `distance` from the camera to the geometry, we also have `dradius`, the rate of change in pixel radius over distance. We can take a dot product to compute a glance factor just like before, and the trigonometry is similar:

```
def glance := glsl.dot(dir, N).abs().reciprocal()
def fradius := (pixelRadius + dradius * distance) * glance * (1.0 + K)
def fwidth := fradius * 2.0
```

And now we have `fwidth` just like in GLSL. Finally, when it comes time to reflect, we'll want to adjust the change in radius by integrating our second-derivative curvature into our first derivative:

```
def dradiusNew := dradius + H * fradius
```

The results are satisfactory. The fragments might be a little too big; it's hard to tell if something is overly blurry or just properly antialiased. I wonder whether Amanatides used a different set of equations to handle curvature; I spent far too long at a whiteboard deriving what ended up being pleasantly simple operations.

[image: A mirrored sphere hovering above and reflecting a checkerboard pattern which covers the ground]

This image was not supersampled; each pixel had one fragment with one ray and one cone.